# Error in Tax Return GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, border-layout, jgrasp

I've been trying to make this Tax Return Program to work but im having some difficulties. It runs sure, but the "Calculation Button" does not work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Tax extends JFrame
{

private int NewNetPay = 0;

private JPanel panelN;
private JPanel panelS;
private JPanel panelE;
private JPanel panelW;
private JPanel panelC;

private JButton calcButton;
private JButton resetButton;
private JButton exitButton;

private JRadioButton hohRB;
private JRadioButton marriedJRB;
private JRadioButton marriedSRB;
private JRadioButton singleRB;

private JCheckBox mortgageCB;
private JCheckBox charitableCB;
private JCheckBox childCB;
private JCheckBox educationCB;

private JTextField childTF;
private JTextField mortgageTF;
private JTextField charitableTF;
private JTextField educationTF;

private JLabel firstName;
private JTextField name1TF;
private JLabel lastName;
private JTextField name2TF;
private JLabel gross;
private JTextField grossTF;

private JLabel netPay;
private JTextField netPayTF;


final int WIN_WIDTH = 500;
final int WIN_HEIGHT = 300; 

public static void main (String[] args)
{
   new Tax();
}   


public Tax()
{
   setTitle("CSC142 Tax Calculator");
   setSize(WIN_WIDTH,WIN_HEIGHT);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setLayout(new BorderLayout(20, 20));
   buildPanel();
   //add(panel);
   setVisible(true);

 }
   private void buildPanel()
   {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        hohRB = new JRadioButton("Head of Household");
        marriedJRB = new JRadioButton("Married, Jointly");
        marriedSRB = new JRadioButton("Married, Seperately");
        singleRB = new JRadioButton("Single");

        ButtonGroup radioGroup = new ButtonGroup();

        radioGroup.add(hohRB);
        radioGroup.add(marriedJRB);
        radioGroup.add(marriedSRB);
        radioGroup.add(singleRB);

        mortgageCB = new JCheckBox("Mortgage");
       charitableCB = new JCheckBox("Charitable Donation");
        childCB = new JCheckBox("Child Deduction");
       educationCB = new JCheckBox("Education Expenses");

       ButtonGroup checkGroup = new ButtonGroup();

       checkGroup.add(mortgageCB);
       checkGroup.add(charitableCB);
       checkGroup.add(childCB);
       checkGroup.add(educationCB);

        calcButton = new JButton(" Calculate Taxes ");
        resetButton = new JButton(" Reset Values ");
        exitButton = new JButton (" Exit Application ");



      panelN = new JPanel();
      panelS = new JPanel();
      panelE = new JPanel();
      panelW = new JPanel();
      panelC = new JPanel();

      add(panelN, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
      add(panelS, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      add(panelE, BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(panelW, BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(panelC, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      panelN.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelN, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
      panelS.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelS, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
      panelE.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelE, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      panelW.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelW, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      panelC.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelC, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

      panelW.add(hohRB);
      panelW.add(marriedJRB);
      panelW.add(marriedSRB);
      panelW.add(singleRB);

      JTextField childTF = new JTextField();
      childTF.setPreferredSize( new Dimension (10,10));
      JTextField mortgageTF = new JTextField();
      mortgageTF.setPreferredSize( new Dimension (10,10));
      JTextField charitableTF = new JTextField();
      charitableTF.setPreferredSize( new Dimension (10,10));
      JTextField educationTF = new JTextField();
      educationTF.setPreferredSize( new Dimension (10,10));

      childTF.setEnabled(false);
      mortgageTF.setEnabled(false);
      charitableTF.setEnabled(false);
      educationTF.setEnabled(false);



      panelC.add(mortgageCB);
      panelC.add(mortgageTF);
      panelC.add(charitableCB);
      panelC.add(charitableTF);
      panelC.add(childCB);
      panelC.add(childTF);
      panelC.add(educationCB);
      panelC.add(educationTF);

      panelS.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(35,0)));
      panelS.add(calcButton);
      panelS.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,0)));
      panelS.add(resetButton);
      panelS.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,0)));
      panelS.add(exitButton);

      panelW.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Filing Status"));
      panelC.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Deductions"));




      JTextField name1TF = new JTextField();
      JTextField name2TF = new JTextField();
      JTextField grossTF = new JTextField();

      JLabel firstName = new JLabel("   First Name   ");
      JLabel lastName = new JLabel("   Last Name   ");
      JLabel gross = new JLabel("   Gross Income   ");    


      panelN.add(firstName);
      panelN.add(name1TF);
      panelN.add(lastName);
      panelN.add(name2TF);
      panelN.add(gross);
      panelN.add(grossTF);

      JLabel netPay = new JLabel("Net Pay");
      JTextField netPayTF = new JTextField(1);

      panelE.add(netPay);
      panelE.add(netPayTF);

      calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());


      }



      private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
      {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
         {
            String inputo;

            inputo = grossTF.getText();




            if (mortgageCB.isSelected())
               NewNetPay = Integer.parseInt(inputo) - 10000;
            else if (charitableCB.isSelected())
               NewNetPay = Integer.parseInt(inputo) - 5000 ;
            else if (childCB.isSelected())
               NewNetPay = Integer.parseInt(inputo) - 1000;
            else if (educationCB.isSelected())
               NewNetPay = Integer.parseInt(inputo) - 20000;







         netPayTF.setText(" " + NewNetPay);


         }
      }   

   }   `enter code here`
```

I am trying to make it so that a user enters a salary in the gross income text field, then depending on what checkbox they click they will get a deduction. Then finally, the amount will be displayed in the net pay text field.

Comment: `
  name1TF = new JTextField();
  name2TF = new JTextField();
  grossTF = new JTextField();

  firstName = new JLabel("   First Name   ");
  lastName = new JLabel("   Last Name   ");
  gross = new JLabel("   Gross Income   ");
` 
use the global variables

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", you must also way *how*. We aren't telepaths.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `JTextField grossTF = new JTextField();` where `grossTF` is a local Variable to the frame, and trying to get data from `inputo = grossTF.getText();` where `this.grossTF` which is a class member that would be initialized null when getting the data, hence you'd get a NPE.

Also you've done the same for `netPayTF`, change them to..

`netPayTF = new JTextField(1);` & `grossTF = new JTextField();`

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for clarifying things for me I was quite confused.